# Detect when sound(music) starts playing and ends?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How can i detect in my app when any music app ( or youtube) starts palying music ?
I've tried isPlaying() method of MusicPlayer but it didnt work .

Comment: Do you have code showing where you start the music?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very large number of ways to interact with media in Android, and each has it's own problems.  However, I have had good luck so far with [AudioManager.isMusicActive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive()).  I haven't tested it exhaustively to see that it works with all apps, but it does with the first five or so results for "music" on the Play Store.

```
private AudioManager audioManager;
audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
boolean playing = audioManager.isMusicActive();
```